# Tags about food

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-management

I’m trying to clean up tags.* I noticed that we have:

- [nutrition](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition), [diet](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet), [food](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food), [eating](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eating)

I think we probably don’t need all four, but I’m trying to decide what to merge where and what is a synonym of what. I was initially thinking to make them all synonyms of [nutrition](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition), but looking through the current questions in each tag, sometimes they seem distinct. For instance, under [food](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food): [Why am I advised not to eat immediately before exercise?](https://health.stackexchange.com/q/224/165) This doesn’t seem totally appropriate for [nutrition](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition). Any opinions?

---

<sub>*Apologies all around for the disruptive large-volume bumping.</sub>

---

Update: As suggested in [the top answer to this question](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/a/238/165) (and mostly supported by the only other answer), I merged [food](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) and [eating](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eating) both into [nutrition](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) and created synonyms to remap future tags accordingly. I also edited the tag wiki for [diet](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) to specify the narrower sense of this term and clarify the relationship with the [nutrition](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition). If there are corrections, objections, or other feedback, please comment or answer here as appropriate.

Comment: "*Apologies all around for the disruptive large-volume bumping." - Being helpful and keeping things tidy doesn't require apologies but thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me [eating](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eating) and [food](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food) should be regrouped under [nutrition](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition).

The question [Why am I advised not to eat immediately before exercise?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/224/why-am-i-advised-not-to-eat-immediately-before-exercise) is not so much about [food](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/food), finally, but about sport or exercise. So maybe any tag related to food is just not so relevant here. And should it be, [nutrition](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) is acceptable, even if not perfectly appropriate.

[diet](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) is a bit more complicated. It is a subset of [nutrition](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) that is interesting on its own. As technically we cannot define a hierarchy, I think [diet](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) should be kept separate but always used in conjunction with [nutrition](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition)<sup>1</sup>. Simply because some users may want to search for [diet](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) questions only while those who are searching for [nutrition](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nutrition) are also interested in [diet](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diet) things.

---

<sup>1- Users should be advised of this best practice. A [chat discussion with Susan](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21273678#21273678) (thanks!) tends to show we have simple ways to do that. We can for example include a statement to the wiki description of the "diet" tag</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Eating and food I think can go away.

I would keep both nutrition and diet, as there is a difference between them.

Diet is the sum of all food that a person (or other living organism) takes in to sustain life.

Nutrition is the process by which the body breaks down and uses the nutrients obtained from the diet.

They are very similar and do go somewhat hand in hand, but I think there is enough of a difference that both tags would be used.

Comment: I can't really make them just go away - they need to be merged into something (or manually re-tagged), and if we don't also define them as synonyms of something they will probably just pop right back up. I agree in principle, though - both should become synonyms of something. Shlubu (if I understand correctly) was suggesting using the more narrow definition of "diet" (a prescribed eating pattern), defining it in the tag wiki excerpt as such, and then merging/synonymizing everything else with "nutrition." That ends up with the same two tags as your suggestion. Any problem with that?

Comment: (It is possible to blacklist tags, but the community team has to be involved, and if there's an obvious synonym I think that's preferred.)

Comment: I meant go away as in be made synonyms.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: @Susan Yes, this is exactly what I meant.